# Javascript associative array return TypeError

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to make simple array (like in php), and I get error: **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '480' of undefined(…)"** where is the problem?

```
var $form = [];

for (var $i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    $form[5][480]['value'][$i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 4 + 1)) + 4;
}
```

**Solution?**

```
var $form = {
    5: {
        480: {
            value: []
        }
    }
};

for (var $i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    $form[5][480]['value'][$i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 4 + 1)) + 4;
}

console.log($form);
```

Comment: ask yourself this - where is `$form[5]` defined?

Comment: "associative arrays" don't exist in JS... here they are called objects...

Comment: Yes, I know, but there is no option to insert without define?

Comment: no, there is not - but you can do something close

Comment: @JaromandaX, please look for my edit, this is good way?

Comment: that's a good hardcoded way, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something close in javascript - this function is possibly not the prettiest way to do it, but it's generic

the first argument is the "root" object, this is followed at least 1 "nodes", and the last argument is the value

```
function assoc(root) {
    var parts = arguments.slice(1);
    var value = parts.pop();
    parts.reduce(function(result, part, index) {
        if (index < parts.length - 1) {
            return result[part] = result[part] || {};
        }
        result[part] = value;
    }, root);
}
```

now your code needs to change like this:

```
var $form = {}; // use an object, not an array
for (var $i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    assoc($form,5,480,'value',$i, Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 4 + 1)) + 4);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify($form));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access `480` off of `$form[5]`, but `$form[5]` is undefined. Before your loop, you are setting `$form = [];` so there's nothing at position `5`. `$form` is an empty array.

By the way, this is an associative array:

```js
var array1, array2, array3;

array1 = [1,2,3];
array2 = [4,5,6];
array3 = [7,8,9];

var $form = [array1, array2, array3];

/*
     $form[0] // array1 - [1,2,3]
     $form[1] // array2 - [4,5,6]
     $form[2] // array3 - [7,8,9]

     $form[0][0] // array1[0] - 1
     $form[0][1] // array1[1] - 2

     ...

     $form[2][2] // array3[2] - 9
*/
```

It looks like what you may want to use is an object.

```js
    $form = {  // initialize $form
      5:{
        480: { value: [] }
      }
    };

    for (var $i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
        $form[5][480]['value'][$i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 4 + 1)) + 4;
    }
```

But if you need to use an array, this will work also:

```js
    $form = [];  // initialize $form
    $form[5] = [];
    $form[5][480] = {value:[]};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var form = {
    "5": {
        "480": {
            "value": []
        }
    }
};

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    form[5][480]['value'].push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 4 + 1)) + 4);
}
```

given, the code you showed, this should work...